# Evangelicals: Evidence King Amraphel was not Hammurabi: Genesis 14:1?

Tags: archaeology

I found the note only on the NIV Study Bible, the rest of good Bible studies ignores the point. NIV note says on Gen 14:1 "Amraphel was king of Shinar. Not the great Babylonian king Hammurapi, as once thought". How has it been discovered that Amraphel was not Hammurabi?

Question to for the Evangelical scholars views only who use and wrote NIV study bible.